# My Textured paint became plain color when I render in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing

First of all I Marked Seam and Unwrapped my model and I started to texture paint but the Render is plain light grey color , I also sculpted it but I don't think that it causes the problem .. Here are some pictures to show , the problem.
[image]
[image]

Comment: make sure to assign this texture to the material on that object ( can you show the material nodes )

Comment: Ok I'll give you a link , http://imgur.com/j8hIjrD

Comment: you are not using nodes,  can you show the material Tab

Comment: Ok , can you also tell me how to do the nodes , Here is the link , http://imgur.com/92bYlyf ... Im a newbie btw to texture painting :/

Comment: ok minutes and i'll post an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the texture needs to be assigned to a material on this object to be visible on the render , and to start using the nodes editor :

- select the object
- in the material tab click <kbd>New</kbd> button to create new material
- click ***use nodes***

[image]

- in the node editor press  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>➝Texture➝Image texture
- in the texture node select you image ( the one you painted )
- connect the texture node to the shader node ( click and drag the dot to the other one )

[image]